# Image button increases cart price when clicked - Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I'm currently working on a plugin that uses image buttons to add a predefined message to the order.

[image]

What I would like to do however is assign a price to each of the buttons, which also gets added to the order. Kind of like a custom option assigned to each button, but something I can code in myself.

Is this possible? I can't find any info to adjust the price of the cart using buttons/code.

Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I might have it...I can set up additional products for the prices I want and assign these to the buttons. I found this question/answer that seems like the right track!

Comment: What you are trying to do appears to be very similar to the content of [this tutorial](http://www.magesolution.com/blog/techniques-show-product-options-in-product-list/). The difference is that the tutorial uses a `<select>` menu for selecting options, whereas you want to use discrete buttons (images) - but the principle should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple javascript, unless you want to do it server side, which would be easy but require mysql.

HTML CODE:

```
<img src="" onclick="item_1()"> //just add the src (path) and some style.
<img src="" onclick="item_2()"> //if you need a third just repeat the same and change the numbers.

<p id="total_order">$0</p> //that's the paragraph that shows the total bill (can be a div too)
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var order = 0;
var price_1 = "price"; //simply change "price" for the price you want
var price_2 = "price";

function item_1() {
order += price_1; //increments the order value by the price of the 1st item
document.getElementById("total_order").innerHTML = "$"+order;
}
//same function repeated but with different number
function item_2() { 
order += price_2;
document.getElementById("total_order").innerHTML = "$"+order;
}
```

I don't know if that's what you're looking for, but I hope it helps.